# Apple support requesting an id to activate the Apple Developer Enrolment

Tags: developer-program

I accidentally wrote the name that’s on my Apple ID on the billing info which is different from the one on my credit card.

- I don’t know how to proceed since if they reject my payment it’s not clear i could re-purchase again.
- I don’t get why these organisations keep asking for identifications as if we should trust them and give our private information away.

Why did Apple support request my identification after purchasing an Apple Developer Program enrolment and was it legitimate?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're upset with Apple. You provided a name that's different from the name on the card. They need to protect themselves to avoid being penalized by the credit card company and for following their rules. A developer account will require you provide more personal info to Apple so if you're not comfortable with this you shouldn't continue with signing up.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) I hope you find this site a valuable source of info/help. Unfortunately, I've had to close this question. No-one here can tell you **why** Apple did something, especially in a situation like this. In addition to this, parts of your question are either too broad and/or primarily opinion-based. You may want to take a look at [What topics can I ask about here?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for more clarity.

Comment: To get answers to these queries, please refer to [Apple Developer Support](https://developer.apple.com/support/) or [Worldwide Telephone Support - Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone/).

Comment: @Monomeeth Why isn’t your comment an answer to this? I think we want developer program questions to be on topic and searchable. Even if a vendor provides support, we generally don’t close questions and have an answer - here’s why you get support from the vendor. (I get there’s other quality / broadness issues here, but an edit can clarify those I believe)

Comment: That's a fair call @bmike - happy with this approach. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is 100% normal and expected since enrolling in an Apple Developer is a legally binding - super high stakes event. You are about to be approved to sign code and push code to the App Store that will be ready to run on 1 billion devices world wide. You also will have banking and legal documents signed that could run into 10,000 dollars a month or even higher.

I would call Apple Developer Support if you don’t understand why that organization is asking for legally binding information.

- https://developer.apple.com/support/
- https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone/

Also, if you haven’t completed the sign up or payment, dev support can’t help you (yet). In that case you need to call Apple online sales support to determine if they can cancel the purchase - let you purchase again since you have money on the line or about to have $100 on the line to pay for a year of service, privilege and access to software and Apple’s marketing and development pre-release documentation. Much of that is covered by non-disclosure agreements that will get you sued if you steal and banned if you abuse the access.

Apple needs to know who you are and the details have to match to get to be a developer as the stakes are quite high for both parties. This could be your job or the careers of 10 people that can’t get paid if you publish apps as part of a company. Same for you, you could get sued if you publish apps with content you don’t own or license.

I’ve moved twice in 2 years and had to send them my driver’s license each time and other documentation just to get my address changed. Being asked for photo ID / banking information / and being called back and checked is par for the course for a developer.

I would recommend you get legal advice if you aren’t comfortable with signing these documents that are about to come your way once your purchase is set. Also, you don’t need to be a paid developer to run Xcode and install code on your personal devices. As a student - you can do almost all the learning you need without even paying to be a developer. Good luck whether or not you join as a paid developer this month.